# How to create custom MySQL queries in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, controller

I am trying to create my own MySQL queries in Cakephp.

This is my `LocationsController.php`:

```
<?php
App::uses('Location', 'Model');
class LocationsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    function index()
    {
        $this->loadModel("Location");
        $this->Location->get();
    }
}
```

This is my `LocationModel.php`:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class LocationModel extends Model {

    public $name = 'Location';

    public function get()
    {
        $this->Location->query("SELECT * FROM locations;");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am just trying to perform a simple query but it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'get' at line 1
```

When I use one of the magic methods like find("all") instead, it works...

Can you see what the problem is? I really can't and I'm only trying to do a simple task!

Comment: If you're in the `Location` model, wouldn't it just be `$this->query('SELECT * FROM locations');` ?

Comment: Check the answer below and let me know what happens next!

Comment: I dont see any sane reason to use a custom query here when you already got the location model and could just do `find(all)`... you should always ask yourself if you really must use a custom query. then you will find out that you never really need them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class name of your Location model should be `Location`, not `LocationModel`.

Because of this, CakePHP will generate a 'generic' model for the Locations database table and use that model instead of your own model. Because this generic model does *not* have a `get()` method, it will execute `get` as a SQL statement, causing the error

Also, inside the Model, you should not use `$this->Location->query();`, but simply `$this->query();`

Comment: does `query()` prevent SQL injection ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales **not** if you pass it a literal query with unescaped variables in it, but it *does* support prepared statements (see the source [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3297)). Use it like this: `$this->query('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id=? OR somefield=?', array(123, 'foo'));`

Answer (score 3):

Location Controller should be:

```
<?php
App::uses('Location', 'Model'); // Y do u need this?
class LocationsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    function index()
    {
        $this->loadModel("Location");
        $this->LocationModel->getLocations(); // I will strongly discourage using get()
    }
}
```

Location Model should be:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class LocationModel extends Model {

    public $name = 'Location';

    public function getLocations() // Try to avoid naming a function as get()
    {
    /** Choose either of 2 lines below **/

        return $this->query("SELECT * FROM locations;"); // if table name is `locations`
        return $this->query("SELECT * FROM Location;"); // if table name is `Location` since your public name is `Location`
    }
}
```

Comment: does `query()` prevent SQL injection ?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't. However, you can check the variables by using php functions like `is_int()` or `ctype_alnum`

Comment: Well, please take a look at this and let me know what you think:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3297

Comment: 2.4.9! `prevent SQL injection` , no it doesn't? Plus, what you showed will be further parsed using func_get_args.. Sanitizing will be slow on process but hasn't hurt anybody :)