# how to get the date from the cakephp query

Tags: php, cakephp

```
$date= $this->Profile->find('all',array(

              'conditions'=>array('date(Add date(DOB,interval (year(curdate())-year(DOB)) year))>=date(now())'),
              'fields'=>array('date(Add date(DOB,interval (year(curdate())-year(DOB)) year)'),

              'limit'=>1,
              'order'=>'date(Add date(DOB,interval (year(curdate())-year(DOB)) year))'
          ));
```

can anyone help me ....

MySQL query:

```
(select date(Adddate(dob,interval (year(curdate())-year(dob)) year)) 
from profiles
where date(Adddate(dob,interval (year(curdate())-year(dob)) year))>=date(now()) 
order by date(Adddate(dob,interval (year(curdate())-year(dob)) year)) limit 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your conditions array is declared like this:

```
'conditions' => array('field >=' => $value) // when condition is >=
'conditions' => array('field <=' => $value) // when condition is <=
'conditions' => array('field' => $value) // when condition is =
```

And if it is not working, maybe you should use [custom queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170852/how-to-create-custom-mysql-queries-in-cakephp) instead of the find function.