# Insert SQL query into controller in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp

I'm using cake php version 2.4.1

I want change this SQL query into PHP code for my controller in cakePHP

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM providers 
WHERE id not in 
    (SELECT c.provider_id 
    FROM token_maps a 
    INNER JOIN token_map_groups b ON b.token_map_id = a.id 
    INNER JOIN token_map_group_providers c on c.token_map_group_id=b.id 
    LEFT JOIN providers p on p.id=c.provider_id 
    WHERE a.id=2
    )
```

I can't use  `$this->Provider->query('sql query');`
because it will give me false result different from when I execute the query in mysql.

can anyone help me?

Comment: If you in model `Provider.php`, use: `$this->query('sql query');`. If you in other model, write your way is ok. If your model class don't load, try `$Provider_Model = ClassRegistry::init('Provider');  $result_array = $Provider_Model->query(...);`.

Answer (score 2):

At first I told you that your approach is not recommended in any MVC framework. You need to declare a method in  Provider model, then you can write cakePHP custom query.

Look at [How to create custom MySQL queries in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170852/how-to-create-custom-mysql-queries-in-cakephp)

Answer (score -1):

If you query gives the exact answer in PHPMYADMIN then make a query like this:

```
$this->loadModel('Provider');

$query = "SELECT id,name FROM providers WHERE id not in (SELECT c.provider_id  FROM token_maps a 
INNER JOIN token_map_groups b ON b.token_map_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN token_map_group_providers c on c.token_map_group_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN providers p on p.id=c.provider_id 
WHERE a.id=2
)";

$this->Provider->query($query);
```

Comment: It's not recommended (on the scale of not-recommended - like just one step below "completely wrong") to put sql in a controller - put it in a model (if raw sql is actually necessary) and call the model method.

Comment: In model by default it will call every where. If you need some place then use in controller

Comment: That's not how models are supposed to be used. raw-sql is not "parameters"